# Unity/C# Prevent multiple entries per letter in a list (from Input Fields)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, input-field

After spending hours scratching my head to try and extract text from a list of input fields, I have figured it out, only to find it adding multiple individual entries per field, in the form of the progress of the word.

Image for clarity:

[image]

I want it to only register an entry when the user is done typing. Here is what I have in terms of code:

```
public void getText() {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
    {
        string input = inputList[i].text;
        textList.Add(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary? Can you use `Enter` key to trigger event `Player done typing`?

Comment: @Morasiu it's unnecessary for the user to press the enter key, unfortunately, as you can exit the field by clicking away from it. I could probably use that to trigger an event... but alas, I don't actually know how to do that. Feel free to provide an example.

Comment: Soo... How do you know if user done typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputfield has an event called "onEndEdit", which is triggered when the user finishes with the field, its triggered on Enter and when exits the field by clicking outside. Here's an example

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(InputField))]
public class InputFieldListener : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
    GetComponent<InputField>().onEndEdit.AddListener(OnEndEdit);

    }
    void OnEndEdit(string s)
    {
        Debug.Log("user entered: "+s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the script is not attached to an InputField, and there's more than one. As it is, I'm getting an error that says "Object reference is not set to instance of an object. However, all my slots for this script are filled.

Comment: I finally figured out how to implement this code. Here is the edited work:

public List<int> numbers;
public List<string> items;

for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
        {
            inputList[i].onEndEdit.AddListener(OnEndEdit);
            numbers.Add(i);
        }
public void OnEndEdit(string s)
    {
        items.Add(s);
    }